# When limiting the domain of a surjective, continuous function, if surjectivity is preserved does that mean that continuity is preserved?

Tags: continuity

If you have a continuous surjective function which is not injective, and you limit the domain of the function such that the function remains surjective and becomes injective, is continuity always preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are topological spaces and $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous, and $A\subseteq X$ is a subspace, then the restriction $f|_A$ is still continuous.

Indeed, for any open $U\subseteq Y$, we have that $(f|_A)^{-1}(U)=A\cap f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$ under the subspace topology.